# MySQL select...into variable yields null, even though data is there

Tags: mysql

My stored procedure performs `SELECT ... INTO var` yielding NULL, but if I repeat the same `SELECT` myself, I get a value.

Here's the relevant part of the schema

```
CREATE TABLE UrlAuthority
(
     id              BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'includes TLD suffix'
    ,UNIQUE(name)
)
ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE UrlFqdn
(
     id              BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,authority       BIGINT NOT NULL COMMENT 'references example.com'
    ,name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'host.example.com'
    ,FOREIGN KEY (authority) REFERENCES UrlAuthority (id)
    ,UNIQUE (authority, name)
)
ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE Url
(
     id              BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,fqdn            BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,path            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    ,FOREIGN KEY (fqdn) REFERENCES UrlFqdn (id)
    ,UNIQUE (fqdn, path)
)
ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And here's the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UrlToId (url TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE host      TEXT;
    DECLARE authority TEXT;
    DECLARE tld       TEXT;
    DECLARE pathtext  TEXT;

    DECLARE authority_tld TEXT;
    DECLARE fqdn          TEXT;
    DECLARE authority_id  BIGINT;
    DECLARE fqdn_id       BIGINT;
    DECLARE url_id        BIGINT;
    DECLARE err           TEXT;

    CALL UnpackURL (url, host, authority, tld, pathtext);

    SELECT JoinHostNames(authority, tld)      INTO authority_tld;
    SELECT JoinHostNames(host, authority_tld) INTO fqdn;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO UrlAuthority (name) VALUES (authority_tld);

    SELECT id
    INTO authority_id
    FROM UrlAuthority
    WHERE name=authority_tld;

    -- LOG ('UrlAuthority', authority_tld, authority_id)

    INSERT IGNORE INTO UrlFqdn (authority, name)
    VALUES (authority_id, fqdn);

    SELECT id
    INTO fqdn_id
    FROM UrlFqdn
    WHERE authority=authority_id AND name=fqdn;

    -- LOG ('UrlFqdn', fqdn, fqdn_id)

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Url (fqdn, path) VALUES (fqdn_id, pathtext);

    -- LOG ('Url', fqdn_id, pathtext)

    SELECT id FROM Url WHERE fqdn=fqdn_id AND path=pathtext;
END
|
```

The `LOG` lines are a bit of metaprogramming, they insert strings into a debug table.

If I run

```
call UrlToId('http://mail4.z.uk/foo/bar');
```

I get these debug messages

```
UrlAuthority authority_tld=z.uk authority_id=1
UrlFqdn fqdn=mail4.z.uk fqdn_id=NULL
Url fqdn_id=NULL pathtext=/foo/bar
```

Clearly the problem is that `fqdn_id=NULL` however, if I manually repeat the query which does `SELECT id INFO fqdn_id` and substitute the values of the variables indicted in the trace:

```
    SELECT id
    -- INTO fqdn_id
    FROM UrlFqdn
    WHERE authority=1 /* authority_id */ AND name='mail4.z.uk' /* fqdn */;
```

This selects `1` as expected.

The `select` gets the data, so why is the variable `NULL` afterwards?

Comment: What does this do? `SELECT JoinHostNames(host, authority_tld) INTO fqdn;`

Comment: `JoinHostNames('mail','google.com')='mail.google.com'` but it also handles an empty `host` argument gracefully.

Comment: Consider using `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` and `LAST_INSERT_ID`; they may simplify your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a while, this one eluded me. [I don't like `SELECT ... INTO`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651), so I really wanted to blame it for your trouble, but no.

Here'e the problem.

```
SELECT id
  INTO fqdn_id
  FROM UrlFqdn
 WHERE authority=authority_id AND name=fqdn;
```

How does MySQL interpret this?

```
SELECT id
  INTO fqdn_id
  FROM UrlFqdn
 WHERE 'mail4' = 1 AND name = 'mail4.z.uk';
/* Impossible WHERE */
/* see DECLARE authority TEXT; */
```

> **“**A local variable should not have the same name as a table column.   If an SQL statement, such as a `SELECT ... INTO` statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.**”**
>
> — http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html

Using the same identifier for a variable and a column name [makes a debugging mess](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56964/11651), one way or another.

Comment: Oh my god THANK YOU. New personal policy: local variable names will have goddamned prefixes.

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT...INTO` by the way? I used to use `@foo` but kept getting caught out by silent typos.

Comment: See the ["I don't like..."](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651) link for my write-up about the issue with `SELECT ... INTO` in contrast with the behavior of assignment from a scalar subquery, e.g. `SET var = (SELECT ...);`.  Unlike the subquery, `SELECT ... INTO` leaves the variable's previous value intact rather than setting it `NULL` if the `SELECT` does not actually match a row.  With cursors and loops, where the variable is reused, this can bite you. Also, yes, good idea: I almost always prefix local (program) variables with `_` whether they need it or not, to avoid ambiguity.